# How to send signals for events in SpriteKit games in a single scene?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to change the background music after a specific event in the same scene. Do I have to use Booleans and update() function or is there a way to do delegation in a single scene?

Sample code would be appreciated. Any advice on how to properly ask these type of questions on stackoverflow would be nice.

Comment: It depends what the specific event is? Collision, touch, timed, other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the SKAction methods.

An example:

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
   self.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("filename.type"), waitForCompletion: false))
}
```

With this action, u play a sound on toucheEnded, but you can use it everywhere u need a sound.

Comment: Can it be done using delegation or some other way? Just want to know if there are other ways of doing this.

Comment: Well it depends on what you want to do.  I said it before, you can use the actions everywhere in your SKScene. And its possible to do this on delegate functions.